# for loop only using 1st key in dict

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to calculate whether or not an item has been delayed. I have a dictionary containing 20+ keys and values, and am trying to loop through the rows in my dataset, and if the dataframe value is above the dict value, it should result in "True".

It seems like the loop is only using the first value in the dict, and I've tried changing it to no avail.

This is the current code I'm using:

```
def delaytest(df):
    for key, value in mydict.items():
        if (key == df["serviceType"]) & (value < (df["delayTime"]/60)):
            return True

        else:
            return False

df["delay"] = df.apply(delaytest, axis=1)
```

Example dict:

```
dict = {"key1": 5,
        "key2": 10,
        "key3": 15}
```

```
df before:
    serviceType   delayTime
    key1          6
    key2          11
    key2          12
    key1          4
    key3          16
    key3          14

df after:
       serviceType   delayTime  delay
    key1          6          True
    key2          11         False
    key2          12         False
    key1          4          False
    key3          16         False
    key3          14         False

df expected:
    serviceType   delayTime  delay
    key1          6          True  
    key2          11         True
    key2          12         True
    key1          4          False
    key3          16         True
    key3          14         False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here is better use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for new Series and compare by column `delayTime`:

```
df["delay"] = df['serviceType'].map(mydict) < df["delayTime"]
print (df)
  serviceType  delayTime  delay
0        key1          6   True
1        key2         11   True
2        key2         12   True
3        key1          4  False
4        key3         16   True
5        key3         14  False
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['serviceType'].map(mydict))
0     5
1    10
2    10
3     5
4    15
5    15
Name: serviceType, dtype: int64
```

If `map` with value not matched, get missing values and output of comparison are `False`s:

```
mydict = {"key1": 5,
        "key2": 10,
        "key4": 15}

df["delay"] = df['serviceType'].map(mydict) < df["delayTime"]
print (df)
  serviceType  delayTime  delay
0        key1          6   True
1        key2         11   True
2        key2         12   True
3        key1          4  False
4        key3         16  False
5        key3         14  False

print (df['serviceType'].map(mydict))
0     5.0
1    10.0
2    10.0
3     5.0
4     NaN
5     NaN
Name: serviceType, dtype: float64
```

EDIT:

For possible map by multiple values create helper `DataFrame` and `merge` with left join:

```
pairs = [('cat1','prov1', 'content1'),
         ('cat2','prov2', 'content2'),
         ('cat3','prov3', 'content3')]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(pairs, columns=['category','provider','contentType'])
print (df1)

df = df.merge(df1, how='left')
```

Comment: thank you jezrael, both your answer and the other answer seemed to work, but on my dataframe your answer took 1.95ms compared to 499ms.

Comment: @davo777 - What is number of values if, elif?

Comment: i was wondering if there was a more efficient way of writing this loop as well?
def contentType(df):
    if (df["category"] == "cat1") and (df["provider"] == "prov1"):
        return "content1"
    elif (df["category"] == "cat2") and (df["provider"] == "prov2" or df["provider"] == "prov3"):
        return "content2"
    else:
        return "content3"

df["contentType"] = df.apply(contentType, axis=1)

Answer (score 2):

> if the dataframe value is above the dict value, it should result in "True".

Undestandable. But in your code, you also return `False` if you don't hit `True`. So with the first element, you always return something, therefore exiting the function. ;)

Get rid of the `else` with the `return False` and it should work:

```
def delaytest(df):
    for key, value in mydict.items():
        if (key == df["serviceType"]) & (value < (df["delayTime"]/60)):
            return True

df["delay"] = df.apply(delaytest, axis=1)
```

Comment: I have only answered and explained your question that was `for loop only using 1st key in dict` / `It seems like the loop is only using the first value in the dict, and I've tried changing it to no avail.` If there are further problems, they were not put in this question.